# Почему запрос блокируется, если CORS разрешил его?

Tags: javascript, запрос, cors

Есть такой `javascript`:

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('PUT', 'https://my.stripo.email/cabinet/stripeapi/v1/userInfo', true);
req.withCredentials = true;
req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
req.send();
```

Я размещаю его на какую-то страницу на сервере, и захожу на неё через браузер. Т.к. метод `PUT` не безопасен, то сначала будет выполнен `CORS preflight` запрос:

```
OPTIONS /cabinet/stripeapi/v1/userInfo HTTP/1.1
Host: my.stripo.email
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Referer: https://myorigin.com/some_url
Origin: https://myorigin.com
Connection: close
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Ответ приходит такой:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 17 Jan 2020 08:39:56 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://myorigin.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
```

Как я понял, удаленный сервер разрешил отправить `PUT` запрос с данного `origin` с моим заголовком `content-type` и куками:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://myorigin.com <-- разрешил запрос с моего origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT <-- разрешил метод PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type <-- разрешил мой заголовок content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true <-- разрешил отправить запрос с куками
```

Но в консоли браузера получаю:

> Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на https://my.stripo.email/cabinet/stripeapi/v1/userInfo. (Причина: неудача канала CORS preflight).
>   Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на https://my.stripo.email/cabinet/stripeapi/v1/userInfo. (Причина: не удалось выполнить запрос CORS).

Что я понял неправильно?

Comment: А почему ответ с кодом 401 ?

Comment: браузер трактует это как ошибку и на заголовки вообще не смотрит. ответ должен быть с каким нибудь успешным кодом, обычно 302

Comment: @Mike Ох, действительно. На код ответа вообще не посмотрел. Если дело действительно в этом, то оформите, как ответ?

Comment: Вы проверьте на всякий случай и скажите заработало или нет. вдруг еще что нибудь ...

Comment: @Mike Что проверить? Хост https://my.stripo.email мне не принадлежит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ответ с кодом 401, браузер трактует это как ошибку и на заголовки вообще не смотрит. Ответ должен быть с каким-нибудь успешным кодом, обычно 302.